# canvas draw text- cant get strings

Tags: android, drawtext

```
String str = new String();
str = "111";
x = width / 2;
y = Math.round(height / 1.3);

while (pressed != true){
    if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) 
        continue;
    Canvas c = holder.lockCanvas();
    c.drawBitmap(galaxy, 0, 0, null);
    c.drawBitmap(player, x - (player.getWidth() / 2), y - (player.getHeight() / 2), null);
    c.drawText("111", c.getWidth() / 12, c.getHeight() / 15, timerpaint);

    holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
}
```

I tried to put the `str` insted "111" in the "drawText" function, and it didn't write anything, I'm not sure why.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
String str = new String(); 
str = "111";
```

With this:

```
String str = " 111";
```

Hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

Add the

```
Paint paint = new Paint(); 
paint.setColor(Color.BLACK); // any color you like  
paint.setStyle(Style.FILL); 
canvas.drawPaint(paint);
```

before you start painting